# Expo react ios build is not properly working in iPad

Tags: ios, react-native, ipad, expo, ipa

I have developed an expo react native app and it is working correctly when i tested with android and iPhone devices through the expo client app.
But I am having issues when I install its ipa file in iPad. (iPa has been generated through the expo build command with adhoc profile cert). The issue is about the app's screen are zoom in and not fit into the iPad screen. But this is correctly working in iPhone tested in 5s.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your `app.json` file

```
{
  "expo": {
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    }
  }
}
```

[Expo docs](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/configuration.html) for `app.json`.

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode deployment info, you should set Devices as Universal.

**Target -> Deployment Info -> Devices -> Universal**